# Make one-to-one relation to many tables in EF

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I want to have one table with pictures for many other objects, lets say for Meals, Ingridents, ...

One Picture is for particular class (say Meal). This way I could have many tables with PictureId as FK, but can't apply this 2nd data annotation attribute.

```
public class Picture
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Ingridient"), ForeignKey("Meal")] //<---here I get error
    public int PictureId { get; set; }

    //properties
    public byte[] PictureData { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Ingridient Ingridient { get; set; } //1 - 1
    [Required]
    public virtual Meal Meal { get; set; } //1 - 1
}
```

I think I don't follow convention but please tell me how to fix it.
Why PictureId can't be a FK in many tables (Meals, Ingridients, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could have many tables with PictureId as FK

Then those other Entities should have the Foreign Key properties and Navigation Properties.

eg

```
public class Meal
{

  public int MealId {get;set;}

 //  ...
  public int? PictureId {get;set;}
  public virtual Picture Picture {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: one question: Will it be possible to create image for Meal without having Ingridient object created?

Comment: You don't have to have _any_ navigation properties on Picture.  And they would be collections, not single values, as multiple Meal objects could, in this model, have the same Picture.